# How to get TimeZone abbreviation

Tags: ios, uitableview, nstimezone

I want to create a list of time zones.
But I got the following error at timeZone.abbreviation.

-[__NSCFString abbreviation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19cb80b0

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = timeZone.abbreviation;  // <- Error Here
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = timeZone.description;
    cell.accessoryType = (timeZone == self.timeZone)? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark :UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

I tried to search on the internet but I cannot find the solution so far.
Please give me some advice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:[[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.textLabel.text = timeZone.abbreviation;  // <- Error Here
cell.detailTextLabel.text = timeZone.description;
```

Your current code gets an array of *NSStrings*, not NSTimeZones. This should give you an NSTimeZone, and then you can get the [`abbreviation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimeZone/abbreviation) property on it.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimeZone/knownTimeZoneNames

```
[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]
```

returns a list of String ids of the timezones - so your timezone object actually contains a NSString not a NSTimeZone object. So you have to do:

```
NSString *timeZoneID = [[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timeZoneID];
```

to get the real timezone object to call abbreviation on